# How to access value in QuerySet Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating a simple Pizza Delivery website and trying to add an option to choose a topping. When I want to print Ingredients it returns QuerySet and Values in it separated by a comma. Is there any option how can I get values based on their variable names (ex. ingredients.all[0].toppingName -> cheese) or is there any methods which allows to get values separately. Of course, kludge with .split works but it is awful

[image]
[image: Models]

UPD:

As for admin panel the provided solution worked. But it does not work in html template, so I found this code. Maybe it will useful for somebody.

[image]

Comment: It's not very clear what your end goal is? Is it to not show the price when you display a topping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django, if you want to get only a specific column value you can use

```
Model.objects.all().values('column_name')
```

You can also filter the queryset and get values as

```
Model.objects.filter(condition).values('column_name')
```